# How to pass arguments to a async function while using requests-html

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

I want to build the link in async function by passing arguments,from my get_daraz function.

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession


asession = AsyncHTMLSession()


async def get_daraz_page(keyword, page_no):
    template_link = 'https://www.daraz.com.np/catalog/?_keyori=ss&from=input&page={page_no}&q={keyword}&spm=a2a0e.11779170.search.go.287d2d2bVToBsh'
    r = await asession.get(template_link)
    return r

def getDaraz(search):
    results=asession.run(get_daraz_page(search,1))
    print (results)

getDaraz("Mouse")
```

It Gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_daraz_page' was never awaited
```

thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

By requests-html, I got no links at all.

I suggest BeautifulSoup, Requests, and Json. Here is my code.

```
'''
Build links list.
With BeautifulSoup, Requests, and Json.
To avoid ban/ block, delay for 10 to 20 seconds randomly after requests.
'''


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
import time
import json


def delay():
    # Delay for 10 to 20 seconds randomly.
    sleep = random.randint(10, 20)
    time.sleep(sleep)


def make_soup(url, parser):
    response = requests.get(url)
    delay()
    data = response.text
    if parser == 'html.parser':
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
    return soup

def build_list():
  url = 'https://www.daraz.com.np/catalog/?q=mouse&_keyori=ss&from=input&spm=a2a0e.11779170.search.go.287d2d2bd0IOUA'
  parser = 'html.parser'
  soup = make_soup(url, parser)
  # 
  json_tags = soup.find_all('script', {'type': 'application/ld+json'})[1].string
  json_data = json.loads(json_tags)
  links = []
  for item in json_data['itemListElement']:
    links.append(item['url'])
    print(item['url'])
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
  build_list()
```

And this' the result.

```
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/micropack-excalibur-gaming-wired-mouse-g-860-i104220875.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/fantech-x15-phantom-wired-gaming-mouse-i100928540.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/redragon-m801-pc-gaming-mouse-led-rgb-backlit-mmo-9-programmable-buttons-mouse-with-macro-recording-side-buttons-rapid-fire-button-for-windows-computer-gamer-wired-black-i104116249.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/fantech-x16-gaming-mouse-4200-dpi-adjustable-optical-cable-mouse-6-button-macro-for-mouse-gamer-fps-lol-ergonomic-mouse-i103259161.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/fantech-t532-wired-mouse-i100928918.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/fantech-w188-24ghz-wireless-mouse-i100934719.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/fantech-x5s-zeus-computer-wired-mouse-4800-dpi-usb-optical-pc-gaming-mouse-6d-for-pclaptop-i100007184.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/dell-optical-mouse-black-i104330431.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/fantech-raigor-ii-wg10-gaming-mouse-i103261633.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/fantech-w189-24ghz-wireless-mouse-i100924993.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/jedel-6d-optical-gaming-mouse-for-computerpc-laptop-with-led-infrared-micro-6d-dpi-adjustment-i103209858.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/jedel-usb-optical-mouse-i100366102.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/generic-24ghz-1200dpi-wireless-optical-mouse-usb-rolling-car-model-mouse-for-tablet-pc-i103147712.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/sunsonny-s-m3s-gaming-mouse-i103218451.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/razer-deathadder-multi-color-ergonomic-gaming-mouse-comfortable-grip-worlds-most-popular-gaming-mouse-i104160830.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/logitech-b170-wireless-optical-mouse-910-004659-i14400.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/micropack-m101-mouse-optical-i30608.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/dell-usb-optical-wired-mouse-m5111-i103237876.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/redragon-ranger-m910-wired-gaming-mouse-12400-dpi-i104256717.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/dell-usb-optical-wired-mouse-m360-i104838908.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/limeidi-x1-24ghz-2400dpi-wireless-rechargeable-gaming-mouse-backlight-i103299466.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/24g-best-quality-wireless-optical-mouse-assorted-color-i103331286.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/redragon-m705-high-performance-wired-gaming-mouse-i104278047.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/fantech-wgc1-wireless-mouse-charging-design-rgb-and-2400dpi-adjustable-gaming-mouse-pixart-3212-game-chips-for-mouse-gamer-i103255259.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/jeqang-wired-usb-gaming-mouse-i101114219.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/dell-24g-best-quality-wireless-optical-mouse-i104032175.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/gloross-g501-gaming-mouse-with-mouse-pad-i101672317.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/fantech-hive-ux2-gaming-mouse-i104210128.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/r8-a6-wireless-bluetooth-charging-mouse-with-rgb-i104816388.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/dell-usb-optical-wired-mouse-m5111-i104862052.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/lenovo-mini-optical-mouse-i100824202.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/jedel-gaming-mouse-gm740-original-i104798245.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/jedel-w450-wireless-optical-mouse-1000-dpi-i104776750.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/r8-1611-led-accurate-gaming-mouse-i404316.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/jedel-mst-1080g-2-usb-optical-mouse-black-i176104.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/dell-usb-optical-wired-mouse-m5111-i104546789.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/prolink-wireless-optical-mouse-pmw6005-i100838336.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/24-ghz-wireless-mouse-with-usb-20-reciever-i100680189.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/wiwu-wm101-bluetooth-wireless-rechargeable-mouse-i104868803.html
https://www.daraz.com.np/products/black-wireless-mouse-i112671.html
```